# where we can see heart beat of sensor in zigbee call fow?

Tags: iot, sensors, zigbee

The question is about zigbee network; does the nodes (routers, end devices) send some keep alive messages or Heart beat to prevent time out? Or can't a node ping out?

Just a pointee to the correct parameters or what we call that attribute in zigbee call flow? that would be great help. I know that you can set the POLL_RATE for data request, to get queued messages.